# How do I use the jQuery and jQuery UI that is hosted on google?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The code works on codecademy, but not when I try to do it on my own. This is what I have right now:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: fixed that, but still doesn't work

Comment: What happens when you copy one of those URI's into a browser tab?

Comment: Is your `script.js` not working? Most probably because you have to import all jQuery before it.

Comment: what you want to do is, go to that url, copy the file contents and paste into a file called jquery.min.js and add it to your repo that way - take this scenario: google goes down. That means all of your site's jquery no longer works - hosting it local to the repo means 100% access to it.. as long as the site itself isn't down.

Comment: load your script after loading the jquery libraries,

Comment: A bunch of code shows up in the browser for both URLs

Comment: `The code works on codecademy, but not when I try to do it on my own` Doesn't work how? What are the errors you get? The CDN links look valid and work fine. Do you have `script.js` where it is expected to be? Do you have a `script.js` file?

Comment: I moved the script.js under the importing, but it still doesn't work. The js file just has one function to format the html elements, but it's just showing up as text in the browser.

Comment: Yes, the script.js file is located in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: Have a look at this and see if you can add a working sample of what you have ► [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) There is a snippet functionality in SO when asking a question or JsFiddle, etc.. If it works all fine there and it only doesn't work locally for you it will be hard to figure out what's wrong

Comment: what error do you get in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script.js uses jquery then you need to reorder your scripts.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Works for me... I found this at: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Where are you placing the `<script>` tag in your code? The location of the tag matters relative to your other scripts.

Comment: location only matters relative to other scripts. E.g. don't place bootstrap framework js before jquery - but it doesn't matter where you place your script tags page wise

Comment: Edited for clarification

Comment: the order I've put it is: jQuery, jQuery UI, script.js file, bootstrap, and css file